# Tire - sort by number of related object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I have something like this in my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Model

  has_many :followers, :through => :as_followed_followings, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "follower_id", :uniq => true

  ...

  def self.search(params)
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per]) do
    end
  end

end
```

I would like the return an array of users ordered by the count of followers that user has.

**So what is the correct way to define mappings and indexes to search through nested object with count property ?**

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by creating  another field on `users` table and index that value instead of performing nested search in runtime.

This may not be the best solution but I have deadline. Any better solution is welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

Trying with ...

```
AsFollowedFollowing.count(:group => :follower_id, :order => "count_all DESC")
```

This is Ordered Hash that contains `user_id => count`

If you want to loop this hash, try following

```
# in controller
@counts = AsFollowedFollowing.count(:group => :follower_id, :order => "count_all DESC")
@users = User.where(:id => @counts.map{|k,_| k})

#in view
<% @counts.each do |k, v| %>
  <% user = @users.find{|u| u.id == k} %>
  <div><%= user.name %> | <%= v %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: is `count` a DSL from elasticsearch ?

Comment: Sorry, actually I don't know elasticsearch. count is method of ActiveRecord::Model.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it's off topic since my question is about elasticsearch and tire gem :)